# Check if numeric input value exists in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to check if a number entered exists in an array. I've tried many things and haven't got anything to work.

```
function start() {
    var arrNum = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20];
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var numberExist = document.getElementById('numberExist').innerHTML;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++) {
        if (input === arrNum[i]) {
            alert('input');
            numberExist = ('The number ' + input + 'exists in the array');
        } else {
            numberExist = ('The number ' + input + 'does not exist in the array');
        }
    }

    var arrNum = arrNum.join(' ');
    document.getElementById('listOfvalues').innerHTML = ('The values in the array are ' + arrNum);
}
```

Comment: Use in operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript) the title might sounds wrong but it's exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few pointers:

- You need to cast your `input.value` to an integer, e.g. using the unary `+` operator, because the [`HTMLInputElement#value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties) property returns a string.
- Your `else` block will run on the first for-loop iteration unless you
  move it *outside* of the loop body.

```js
function start() {
  var arrNum = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20]
  var input = +document.getElementById('input').value
  var numberExist

  for (var i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++) {
    if (input === arrNum[i]) {
      numberExist = 'The number ' + input + ' exists in the array'
    }
  }
  if (!numberExist) {
    numberExist = 'The number ' + input + ' does not exist in the array'
  }
  document.getElementById('listOfvalues').textContent =
    'The values in the array are ' + arrNum.join(' ')
  document.getElementById('numberExist').textContent = numberExist
}

start()
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input" value="18">
<div id="listOfvalues"></div>
<div id="numberExist"></div>
```

Of course, as others have pointed out, this example can be greatly simplified using the [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method:

```js
function start() {
  var array = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20]
  var input = +document.getElementById('input').value
  var numberExist = array.indexOf(input) < 0
    ? 'The number ' + input + ' does not exist in the array'
    : 'The number ' + input + ' exists in the array'

  document.getElementById('listOfvalues').textContent =
    'The values in the array are ' + array.join(' ')
  document.getElementById('numberExist').textContent = numberExist
}

start()
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input" value="18">
<div id="listOfvalues"></div>
<div id="numberExist"></div>
```

Comment: What is purpose of `var arrNum = arrNum.join(' ')` at first stacksnippets?

Comment: In OP's original code, I think the goal was to print the values of `arrNum` separated by spaces. The intermediate assignment to `arrNum` is unnecessary, though; I removed it in the second example but I see I forgot to do so in the first. Let me edit and combine a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) function 
Eg:

```
arr = [1, 4, 18, 5, 10];
arr.indexOf(4); //returns 4
arr.indexOf(20); //returns -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexOf` method

```
var arrNum = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20];

function checkNumber(x){
 if(arrNum.indexOf(x)!=-1){
    alert('number exist')
 }
 else{
 alert('dont exist')
 }

}
checkNumber(8) // alert don't exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Array prototype has a [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) `indexOf` which returns the index of the element, if such exists, -1 otherwise.

In ES6 `includes` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is added, which returns true/false depending on element's existence.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function checkIfExists(arr, num){
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i +=1){
      if(num === arr[i]){
        return true;
      }
  }
  return false;
}

var arrNum = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20];
var userInput = document.getElementById('user-input');

arrNumStr = arrNum.join(",");
    document.getElementById('listOfvalues').innerHTML = ('The values in the array are ' + arrNumStr);
    
document.getElementById('check').onclick = function  () {
var input = Number(userInput.value); // Using Number to convert from string to number
    
    //if (arrNum.indexOf(input) > -1)
    if (checkIfExists(arrNum,input)){
        alert('Number is exists')
    }else{
        alert('Number not exists');
    }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="user-input">
<br>
<input type="button" id="check" value="Check">
<br>
<div id="listOfvalues" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

convert `input` value to number which is by default string.

```
var input = +document.getElementById('input').value;
//OR input = Number(document.getElementById('input').value);
//OR input = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value, 10);
```

break the loop if number is found, do not continue running the loop.

```
if (input === arrNum[i]) {
        numberExist.innerHTML = ('The number ' + input + ' exists in the array');
        break;
    }
```

```js
window.onload = start;
function start() {
    var arrNum = [18, 23, 20, 17, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18, 20];
    var input = +document.getElementById('input').value;
    var numberExist = document.getElementById('numberExist');

    for (var i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++) {
        if (input === arrNum[i]) {
            numberExist.innerHTML = ('The number ' + input + ' exists in the array');
            break;
        } else {
            numberExist.innerHTML = ('The number ' + input + ' does not exist in the array');
        }
    }

    var arrNum = arrNum.join(' ');
    document.getElementById('listOfValues').innerHTML = ('The values in the array are ' + arrNum);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input" value="18" onblur="start()"/>
<button onclick="start()">Check</button>
<div id="numberExist"></div>
<div id="listOfValues"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strict equality operator compares types: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/1636522).

```js
console.log("1 == 1 is", 1 == 1);
console.log("1 == \"1\" is", 1 == "1");
console.log("1 === 1 is", 1 === 1);
console.log("1 === \"1\" is", 1 === "1");
console.log("1 === parseInt(\"1\", 10) is", 1 === parseInt("1", 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done with the 'includes' method (not in Edge 13 or earlier).

```
if( arr.includes(valueToFind) ){
```

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `Number()` function. Such as `Number(input)`. Since you input box type is not `Number`. Thus in `input` variable you are always getting string. Thus you need to convert the string to numeric.